# Selecting records by date and time

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

i am having trouble with a select statement on a table (mysql) and no clue what the right solution could be.
It looks quite simple. I am having a couple of records representig a flightlog. There is a field like date, which is the day of the flight an a field named time which is for example the landing time. Now i would like to select all flights before or in a range of particular dates an times to build up a sum of flighthours.

Eventually what i need is to get the actual flighthours summed up to a particular record to be identified by the day of flight and the landingtime.

My first attempt was like this

```
select * from flights where date < "2010-01-01" and landing <= "14:30";
```

But everybody knows (even me now) that this is only displaying records where the landingtime is less or equal "14:30" regardless of the day of flight.

Anybody here able to help me?

Many thx

cdjw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date fields are comprised of date and time.  Combine the two.  Then say `where date between "2010-01-01 00:00:00" and "2010-01-01 14:30:00"` (you know, however you'd format the dates to make that work.)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense ! The only problem i have now ist how to format the two fields into that what i need. I was looking at all the time and datefunctions to concatenate or format the to fields (time,date) in order to compare them as described above. No clue yet.

Comment: How about [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)?  I think you can also compared to strings.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Finally i´ve understood what you were trying to tell me....for some people it takes a bit longer, sorry,

Comment: Now it looks like this: select sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(ftoflighttime(takeoff,landing,landingnd)))) from flights where `aircraft_id` = 1 and concat(flights.date, " ", flights.landing) between "2000-12-10 12:48:00" and "2011-02-22 12:50:00";